# Print input one word per line (K&R 1-12 exercise) attempt

Tags: algorithm, c, design-patterns

I'm currently trying to learn C from the K&R book, reading through and attempting the exercises. I came across exercise 1-12 yesterday and was a little stumped but managed to complete it. I was wondering if someone on here would help me improve it, and also guide me on how to approach testing something like this too.

The exercise is to write a program which "prints input one word per line".

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int main(){

    int c, previous_space;

    previous_space = FALSE;
    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF ){
        if ( c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t' ){
            if ( previous_space == FALSE ){
                putchar('\n');
            }
            previous_space = TRUE;
        }
        else{
            putchar(c);
            previous_space = FALSE;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @greybeard I'll add that in now! Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Algorithmic flaw: Input begins with space**

Input that begins with `' '` prints a new-line.  No point in that.

```
// int previous_space;
// previous_space = FALSE;  
int previous_space = TRUE;
```

Or better with `bool`

```
bool previous_space = true;
```

**Input might not end with a `'\n'`**

A *line* in C:

> each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined

If code wants to handle the case where input does not end with white-space before the `EOF`, post-loop code is needed.

**Other white-spaces**

Aside from OP's 3 listed, there are other white-space characters (carriage return, form-feed, vertical tab, ...), all discernible with `isspace()`.

(See similar idea in [@Jerry Coffin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/241722/29485))

**`int c`**

Good use of an `int` instead of `char`  to save the return value from `gethar()`. Avoided that rookie mistake.

**Alternative**

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  bool previous_space = true;
  int c;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (isspace(c)) {
      if (!previous_space) {
        putchar('\n');
      }
      previous_space = true;
    } else {
      putchar(c);
      previous_space = false;
    }
  }
  if (!previous_space) {
    putchar('\n');
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Conceptual simplification**

Use the inverse flag like `bool need_line_feed = false;` to reduce `!` use in the `if()`s.

Answer (score 3):

A few points to consider.

1. C99 added an actual Boolean type, named `_Bool`, with constants name `_True` and `_False`. By including `<stdboolh.h>`, you get aliases for those spelled `bool`, `true` and `false`. So unless you need to continue using C89, you might consider using these instead of defining your own names and such.
2. When you have a value that's conceptually Boolean in nature (e.g., your `previous_space`) I'd treat it as a Boolean, so to test if it's `false`, I'd prefer to use `if (!previous_space)`.
3. Rather than explicitly checking for every possible white-space character in-line, I'd prefer to move that check into a separately little function of its own. Only this is such a common requirement that the standard library already provides `isspace`, so (at least in real code) it's generally preferred to `#include <ctype.h>`, and us that (but the book probably hasn't introduced this yet, so I wouldn't worry about it a whole lot just yet).